# MPAndroidChart - How to make sure that max Y Label shows up

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to make a line chart using MPAndroidChart that has a Y Axis with a min value of 0 and a max of 255, but I haven't been able to get the max value to show up when viewing the chart. It always shows the top value as something like 240 or 250. I've tried a couple variations of setting the label count but that hasn't helped either. Here is what I'm doing right now.

```
    YAxis yAxis = lineChart.getAxisLeft();
    yAxis.setAxisMaxValue(255);
    yAxis.setAxisMinValue(0);
    yAxis.setLabelCount(5);
```

I'm setting these before I add the data to the chart.